# Convergence in probability and $\mathbb{P}(\vert X_n-Y_n\vert>\varepsilon)\to_{n\to\infty}0.$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Suppose that I have two sequences of random variables $(X_n)_n$ and $(Y_n)_n$ such that $X_n$ converges in probability to a constant $c>0$ and  $$\forall\varepsilon>0\;,\mathbb{P}(\vert X_n-Y_n\vert>\varepsilon)\to_{n\to\infty}0.$$

My dream is that $Y_n$ converges as well in probability to $c$. But intuitively it is false, how can I find an exemple ?

I tried something like that $X_n= 1, \; Y_n= 1-\frac{1}{n}$ but obviously it does not fill the requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $\epsilon>0$,

\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(|Y_n-c|>\epsilon)&=\mathsf{P}(|Y_n-X_n+X_n-c|>\epsilon) \\
&\le \mathsf{P}(|Y_n-X_n|>\epsilon/2)+\mathsf{P}(|X_n-c|>\epsilon/2).
\end{align}

Comment: oups, obvious, thanks